Why can't the value of a map be inferred?
I expect the types of both a and b are inferred as number. Why isn't it the case?
const map1 = new Map([
  ["a", 1]
])
const a = map1.get("a") // number | undefined

const map2 = new Map()
map2.set("b", 2)
const b = map2.get("b") // any

Playground

Not a very expert with typescript but it makes sense to me since the type of map1.get("a") comes from the map1's type which is Map<string, number>.  ts infer that from the given constrator's values. So map1.get returns number. In that way, the type of map2 is Map<any, any> so map2.get returns any

Your expectations are unreasonable, basically. map1 is being created from [string, number][], so it's Map<string, number>. You can add as const to make it Map<"a", 1> (https://tsplay.dev/NlZl5W), but that likely won't behave as you expect with multiple keys, and mapa1.get("a") is now 1 | undefined. And there's no way that map2.set("b", 2) would change the type of map2 - it starts as and continues to be Map<any, any>, because you didn't provide any of the generic arguments.

To recap: the type of new Map() is Map<any, any> and not some kind of "evolving" Map type. TS could presumably implement an evolving Map type, but they haven't, because it's more complicated and nobody has requested it (as far as I can tell, from a brief search of GitHub). A Map<any, any> allows any keys and any values, and it doesn't keep track of anything. Does that fully address the question? If so someone can write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

@jonrsharpe but why does Map<"a", 1> still yield 1 | undefined and not just 1? Btw, how do you shorten the sharing link?

@jcalz so I take that the behavior of map2 is expected as it hasn't been implemented yet. That fully addresses the question for map2. I still have question for the behavior of map1.

what happened to the previous answer? Why is it deleted?


Because that's how the method's defined. 2. Go to https://tsplay.dev without a slug.


Oh, wait, so you're basically asking two questions here. Please [edit] this to ask a single primary question, or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

@jonrsharpe why is it defined like that? Is there an intention behind or is it just a lack of care?

...because that's what the method does return. Again: calling methods doesn't change the type of the class - even if you could initially somehow create a Map explicitly and exclusively from "a" -> 1 at the type level, what about .delete?! And what use would that be? If you only want that specific key-value pair, just write {"a": 1}.

"Is there an intention behind" because usually maps are not guaranteed to contain a given key or not. So map.get(x) can always return undefined if the key-value pair isn't there. m = new Map<"a", number>() says that the map accept only "a" as a key but it doesn't have that - m.get("a") will give you undefined.

@Ooker "what happened to the previous answer? Why is it deleted?" self-deleted by the author.

@VLAZ that fully answers my question. If you can make that an answer I'll accept it

"Why is the previous answer deleted?" - because it was downvoted because it was wrong

In your first usage the key could not exist, in the second there's nothing passed to the constructor to infer from.
You could use a custom class if you need remove undefined from the method:
class MyMap<K, V> extends Map<K, V>{
  get(key: K){
    const v = super.get(key);
    if(v === undefined){
      throw new Error('The key not found');
    }
    return v;
  }
}

const map1 = new MyMap([
  ["a", 1]
])
const a = map1.get("a")
//    ^?

const map2 = new MyMap<string, number>()
map2.set("b", 2)
const b = map2.get("b")
//    ^?

